# Check and uncheck a checkbox in a table row

Tags: jquery

I need your suggestions guys. I have a checkbox's in a table. If I want to check the checkbox something will append and it works. But when I uncheck the checkbox the something I want to happen doesn't work.

Here is my jquery code:

```
 $('.table tbody').on('click','.detailscheck', function(){
    $('.detailscheck').filter(':checked').each(function() {
    var po_no = $(this).closest('tr').find(".pono").val();
    var itemid = $(this).closest('tr').find(".item_id").val();
 if(this.checked) {
       $('div.finaldata').append('<tr> \
       <td><input type="text" class="pono" id="po_no" name="po_no[]" value="'+po_no+'"> \
       <input type="text" id="item_id" class="item_id" name="item_id[]" value="'+itemid+'"></td> \
       </tr>');

        }
        else {
              $('div.finaldata').append('<tr> \
              <td><input type="text" class="pono" id="po_no" name="po_no[]" value="'+po_no+'"> \
              <input type="text" id="item_id" class="item_id" name="item_id[]" value="'+itemid+'"></td> \
             </tr>').remove();
             }
    });
        })
```

Comment: Use `.change` event instead of click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will remove all the unchecked values and remain the checked ones.
You can also use empty() to avoid repetitions.

Not my code, I just found it.

```
$('#test').click(function() {
        $('#out').text('');
        $('#rowclick2 tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
            // this = tr
            $tr = $(this);
            //get row values
            $('#out').append(this.id);
        });
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/fRUUd/35/

Comment: Oh yeah this is I the example I've waiting for.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're loop over `:checked` items only, instead try to loop over all the checkbox like so :

```
  $('.detailscheck').filter(':checkbox');
```

If `$('.detailscheck')` is a checkbox, then just loop over its element by removing filter function like so :

```
 $('.detailscheck').each(function(){...});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions it works but, when I repeat to check it will not check

Comment: Can you provide html snippet or relevant code for this

Comment: $('.table tbody').append('<tr class="details"> \
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="detailscheck" class="detailscheck" id="details"  value="no"></td> \
                <td><input type="hidden" class="pono" id="po_no" name="po_no[]" value="'+getPODetails.po_no+'"> \
                <input type="hidden" id="item_id" class="item_id" name="item_id[]" value="'+getPODetails.itemid+'"><label>'+getPODetails.itemdesc+'</label></td>  </tr>');

Comment: that was my html form.

Comment: Try to change `$('.table tbody')` into `$(document)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

instead of using `if(this.checked)`
try something like this..

```
$(function() {

$('#check').click(function() {

if($(':checkbox').prop('checked') == true)
{
alert("hi");
 }
else if($(':checkbox').prop('checked') == false)
{
alert("hello");
 }

});

});
```

check this fiddle-> http://jsfiddle.net/WnbNC/421/